# Subtract values in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

Wip Return Trouble

In the batch details when I consult material transactions, SHOWS a “WIP ISSUE (2)” AND A “WIP RETURN (2)” so when I'm recovering the data, I do not want the numbers to be displayed. ( wip issue and wip return)

```
SELECT
  mmt.subinventory_code                    subinventario,
  msib.segment1                            segmento,
  msib.description                         descripción,
  SUM(mmln.transaction_quantity)           transacción_primaria,
  mmt.transaction_uom                      medida_primaria,
  SUM(mmln.secondary_transaction_quantity) transacción_secundaria,
  mmt.secondary_uom_code                   medida_secundaria,
  mtl.grade_code                           grado,
  mmt.transaction_type_id,
  mmt.transaction_source_id
FROM mtl_transaction_lot_numbers mmln,
  mtl_material_transactions mmt,
  mtl_system_items_b msib,
  mtl_lot_numbers mtl
WHERE mmt.transaction_source_id IN (
  SELECT bh.batch_id
  FROM gme.gme_batch_header bh, gme.gme_material_details det
  WHERE bh.batch_id = det.batch_id
        AND det.line_type = 1
        AND (TRUNC(actual_start_date) BETWEEN :p_start_date AND TO_DATE(:p_end_date))
        AND bh.organization_id = 269)
      AND mmt.organization_id = 269
      AND mmt.transaction_type_id IN (44, 35, 43, 17)
      AND mmt.transaction_id = mmln.transaction_id
      AND mmt.inventory_item_id = mmln.inventory_item_id
      AND mmt.organization_id = mmln.organization_id
      AND msib.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
      AND msib.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
      AND mtl.lot_number = mmln.lot_number
      AND mtl.organization_id = mmln.organization_id
GROUP BY mmt.subinventory_code,
  msib.segment1,
  msib.description,
  mmt.transaction_uom,
  mmt.secondary_uom_code,
  mtl.grade_code,
  mmt.transaction_type_id,
  mmt.transaction_source_id
ORDER BY mmt.transaction_type_id
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you want to remove any number in parentheses from one of the columns in your result set? You can do that with a regular expression. Please show some data, current output and expected output, preferably from a minimal example - selecting a value from `dual` perhaps, if the details of the actual query aren't important. And can you make the title more meaningful?

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks for your response.Your question: "  you want to remove any number in parentheses from one of the columns in your result set?" Thats I want. I explain in the next paragraph: The column highlights in red has two values, those who are highlighted in yellow. [Click to see the imagen](http://s1255.photobucket.com/user/Leonardo_Tenorio/media/STOF_zpsf857ec1a.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0).  I'm trying to substract only two values, the yellow ones,  but everything  I’m tried is unsuccessfully. My expect output is next: "-1" "Caja" "Fragil" and all the others rows keep  the same value.

Comment: It would be better to show things as text, not images. And this doesn't seem to relate to what's in your question. But, the two rows have different `transaction_type_id` values. If you want to combine them you'll have to leave that column out, or decide which of the two values to keep in an aggregate clause. The output is right for the grouping you've specified.

Comment: @AlexPoole Alex, thanks for your advices. Now, by the morning I had the output that I want. I comment for future references;  I cut the query by two and after that join with a : union all and get rid for the column:  transaction type id. Thanks again Alex.